The bean defined in class path resource could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in URL and overriding is disabled
I implemented a CustomCircuitBreakerFactory class to create separate circuitBreaker configs for my two APIs and have two beans in this class to create circuitbreaker instances.
@Component
public class CustomCircuitBreakerFactory {

    private final ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory circuitBreakerFactory;
    private final CircuitBreakerConfig api1CircuitBreakerConfig;
    private final CircuitBreakerConfig api2CircuitBreakerConfig;

    public CustomCircuitBreakerFactory(
        ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory circuitBreakerFactory,
        CircuitBreakerConfig api1CircuitBreakerConfig,
        CircuitBreakerConfig api2CircuitBreakerConfig) {

        circuitBreakerFactory.getCircuitBreakerRegistry().addConfiguration("api1", api1CircuitBreakerConfig);
        circuitBreakerFactory.getCircuitBreakerRegistry().addConfiguration("api2", api2CircuitBreakerConfig);

        this.circuitBreakerFactory = circuitBreakerFactory;
        this.api1CircuitBreakerConfig = api1CircuitBreakerConfig;
        this.api2CircuitBreakerConfig = api2CircuitBreakerConfig;
    }

    @Bean
    public CircuitBreaker createApi1CircuitBreaker() {
        return circuitBreakerFactory.getCircuitBreakerRegistry().circuitBreaker("api1",api1CircuitBreakerConfig);
    }

    @Bean
    public CircuitBreaker createApi2CircuitBreaker() {
        return circuitBreakerFactory.getCircuitBreakerRegistry().circuitBreaker("api2",api2CircuitBreakerConfig);
    }

The config for circuitBreakrs are in application class like this and I have a bean to create an instance from circuitBreakerFactory:
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.*"})
public class ApiApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApiFacadeApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean("api1CircuitBreakerConfig")
    public CircuitBreakerConfig api1CircuitBreakerConfig() {

        return CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
            .failureRateThreshold(50)
            .waitDurationInOpenState(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
            .permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState(10)
            .slidingWindowSize(100)
            .minimumNumberOfCalls(20)
            .recordExceptions(RuntimeException.class, CallNotPermittedException.class)
            .build();
    }

    @Bean("api2CircuitBreakerConfig")
    public CircuitBreakerConfig api2CircuitBreakerConfig() {
        return CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
            .failureRateThreshold(50)
            .waitDurationInOpenState(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
            .permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState(10)
            .slidingWindowSize(100)
            .minimumNumberOfCalls(20)
            .recordExceptions(RuntimeException.class, CallNotPermittedException.class)
            .build();

    }

    @Bean
    public CustomCircuitBreakerFactory customCircuitBreakerFactory(
        ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory circuitBreakerFactory,
        @Qualifier("api1CircuitBreakerConfig") CircuitBreakerConfig api1CircuitBreakerConfig,
        @Qualifier("api2CircuitBreakerConfig") CircuitBreakerConfig api2CircuitBreakerConfig) {
        return new CustomCircuitBreakerFactory(circuitBreakerFactory, api1CircuitBreakerConfig, api2CircuitBreakerConfig);
    }
}

I used @CircuitBreaker to in my service like this:
@Service
public class Api1Search {

    private static final String SERVICE_NAME = "api1";

    @Override
    @CircuitBreaker(name = SERVICE_NAME, fallbackMethod = "fallback")
    public List<String> search(String input) {
       // logic is implemented
    }


    public List<String> fallback(String input) {
        // logic is implemented
    }
}



@Service
public class Api2Search{

    private static final String SERVICE_NAME = "api2";

    @Override
    @CircuitBreaker(name = SERVICE_NAME, fallbackMethod = "fallback")
    public List<String> search(String input) {  
       // logic is implemented
    }

public List<String> fallback(String input) {
        // logic is implemented
    }
}

and I create a Test class to test the service by circuit breaker:
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {TestClass.TestConfig.class, Api1Search .class, CustomCircuitBreakerFactory.class,
    CircuitBreakerAutoConfiguration.class, CircuitBreakerAspect.class, CircuitBreakerProperties.class,
    TimeLimiterConfiguration.class, TimeLimiterConfigurationProperties.class, ReactiveResilience4JAutoConfiguration.class,
    Api2Search.class} ,properties = "spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true")
public class TestClass {
    
    @Autowired
    Api1Search api1Search;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("createApi1CircuitBreaker")
    CircuitBreaker Api1CircuitBreaker;

    @Autowired
    CustomCircuitBreakerFactory customCircuitBreakerFactoryTest;

    @Autowired
    ReactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory reactiveResilience4JCircuitBreakerFactory;

    @Autowired
    CircuitBreakerRegistry circuitBreakerRegistry;

    @Autowired
    TimeLimiterConfiguration timeLimiterConfiguration;

    @Autowired
    ReactiveResilience4JAutoConfiguration reactiveResilience4JAutoConfiguration;

    @Autowired
    CircuitBreakerProperties circuitBreakerProperties;

    @Autowired
    CircuitBreakerAspect circuitBreakerAspect;

    @Autowired
    TimeLimiterConfigurationProperties timeLimiterConfigurationProperties;

    @Autowired
    Api2Search api2Search;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("createApi2CircuitBreaker")
    CircuitBreaker api2CircuitBreaker;


    @Test
    void api1SearchWhenCircuitBreakerIsClosed() {
        // logic is implemented
    }

   

    @TestConfiguration
    static class TestConfig {

        @Bean("api1CircuitBreakerConfig")
        public CircuitBreakerConfig api1CircuitBreakerConfig() {
            return CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
                .failureRateThreshold(5)
                .waitDurationInOpenState(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                .permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState(5)
                .slidingWindowSize(5)
                .minimumNumberOfCalls(10)
                .recordExceptions(RuntimeException.class, CallNotPermittedException.class)
                .build();
        }

        @Bean("api2CircuitBreakerConfig")
        public CircuitBreakerConfig api2CircuitBreakerConfig() {
            return CircuitBreakerConfig.custom()
                .failureRateThreshold(5)
                .waitDurationInOpenState(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
                .permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState(5)
                .slidingWindowSize(5)
                .minimumNumberOfCalls(10)
                .recordExceptions(RuntimeException.class, CallNotPermittedException.class)
                .build();
        }
    }
}


The application.yml file for application is:
spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true

and the application-test.yaml for test is:
spring:
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true

When I run the test, it works properly, but when I run maven command: mvn clean install I got this error:
The bean CustomCircuitBreakerFactory  defined in class path resource [com/blahblah/blahblah/blahblah/ApiApplication.class], could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/blahblah/blahblah/blahblah/blahblah/blahblah/blahblah/target/blahblah-1.16.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/blahblah/blahblah/blahblah/CustomCircuitBreakerFactory .class] and overriding is disabled.

I enabled overriding and I got this error again. How can I resolve it.
New update:
I resolved this problem by removing @Component from CustomCircuitBreakerFactory Class.

try giving the beans different ids and annotate one with @Primary

@JAsgarov what beans do you mean? I use @Primary in the ApiApplication class and it does not work.

you have CustomCircuitBreakerFactory defined twice. Once as @Component and once as @Bean. Add @Primary over one of the two (whichever).

@JAsgarov CustomCircuitBreakerFactory  is a class, it is not possible to use @Bean on it.

that is not what i said. I said add @Primary on top of the one of the two (doesn't matter that one of them is annotated as bean and another one as compoennt - they are BOTH Spring managed beans). See more about Primary here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-primary

@JAsgarov I added another CustomCircuitBreakerFactory class with name CustomCircuitBreakerFactoryTest to my tesclass. and annotate main CustomCircuitBreakerFactory  with @Primary. but it does not work.
